# ctags or similar tagging system for a kernel source tree

Tags: tags, tagging, ctags, exuberant-ctags

`ctags` is a simple source code tagging system, also integrated in `vi` (and its flavours `nvi`, `vim`, etc.). AFAIK, it builds a plain text file where all the elements (functions, macros, ...) of the source code are indexed. But this file may become too large and unmanageable when the source code tree is extremely huge: this is the case of a kernel (Linux, *BSD, or similar).

- Is still `ctags` or `exuberant-ctags` suitable for a complex source tree like a kernel?
- If not, what tools (with the **same** integration in `vi` as `ctags`) can replace it? This may become subjective, so if possible provide a list of suggested tools: any comments, and references to a guide with the keyboard shortcuts in `vi`, are welcome.

Supported languages should be at least C, C++, assembly. The tool should be usable through [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface). I would principally like to jump to the definition of functions, macros, struct and similar objects (with `ctags`, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> with the cursor over the item name), to their manpages if possible, and back to the code.

The only alternative tool I know so far is `GNU global`, with a [pretty complex `vi` integration](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc_toc.html#Nvi_002d1_002e81_002e5-editor), which seems to be possible only through Perl (and I can't find the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>).

Comment: Maybe switch to some integrated GUI code viewer?

Comment: @Light No, thanks, I prefer a CLI approach.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first point is a resounding **yes**.
You can use ctags to generate a tags file for different subtrees, thus keeping the size of the generated file to a minimum.  At this point, you need to have a mechanism in place for searching for these multiple tags files.  Vim provides this, of course.

I have given some advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54990187/4379143), so you may want to check that out.

Of course, I use exuberant-ctags there, so keep that in mind.